# Force Qt to connect using ip4 instead of ip6?

Tags: qt, ipv4, qnetworkaccessmanager

When using Qt's QNetworkAccessManager to do HTTP GET from a service that's on an IPv4 port, but the same computer *also* has IPv6 functionality (which our service does not use), there is a 2+ second delay before the response is processed. It's as though Qt is attempting to use the IPv6 address first, then times out, then attempts IPv4, where it is successful.

I would like to 'inform' Qt to just use IPv4, to avoid this delay.

I am using Qt 4.8 and using Qt 5 isn't an option at the moment.

Is there a way to 'tell' Qt to just use IPv4? Or avoid this delay some other way?

```
bool float::doRequest(QString* response, const QString& serverfunc, HttpPostData& postdata, int timeout) {
    *response="";
    bool ret=false;

    QString url = "http://" + _host + ":" + QString::number(_port) + "/license.txt";

    postdata["page"] = serverfunc;
    postdata["seed"] = stripChars(QUuid::createUuid().toString());

    QNetworkAccessManager manager;
    QEventLoop q;
    QTimer tT;

    tT.setSingleShot(true);
    connect(&tT, SIGNAL(timeout()), &q, SLOT(quit()));
    connect(&manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), &q, SLOT(quit()));

    QString postdata_string = mapToPostData(postdata);
    QString testurl = url + "?" + postdata_string;
    QNetworkReply *reply = manager.get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(testurl)));

    printf("Starting request. ");

    tT.start(timeout * 1000);
    q.exec();

    printf("Done!"); // 2+ seconds pass between "Starting request." and here when IPv6 is available on server

    if (tT.isActive()) {
        QByteArray data = reply->readAll();
        QTextStream out(&data);
        *response = out.readAll();
        tT.stop();
        ret=true;
    } else {
        // timeout
    }
    reply->close();
    q.quit();

    printf("Done.\n");

    // Other method
    //QString errormsg;
    //ret = SimpleNetworkOp::sendSynchronousPost("Trying...",url,postdata,response,&errormsg);

    delete reply; // clean-up

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't answer your question, but you shouldn't develop something now that cannot use IPv6 if it is available. If the host doesn't advertise IPv6 reachability in DNS or if your local system doesn't have a usable IPv6 address then it won't be usedanyway. Else please develop software that doesn't break when IPv6 becomes more and more deployed, which is already happening very quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I 'solved' the issue by switching to [Chilkat's HTTP library](https://www.chilkatsoft.com/http_cpp_library.asp) for network requests. It lets you specify IPv4 vs. IPv6 preference very easily.

I realize this isn't a correct 'answer' to my own question, since I was asking about Qt, but it's the solution I found easiest, and it works great. This has been in use for over a year now and no problems at all.

Comment: Whoever is downvoting, consider this: Qt *does not allow you to specify IPv4 vs. IPv6*. If you are in a situation where you have legacy code that needs IPv4, and you need to specify this as the type, Qt simply does not have a workable solution for this.